# What is the syntax of URL templates in GitHub REST API?

Tags: rest, github-api

**TL;DR**: Is there a doc somewhere online that fully explains the syntax of GitHub REST API URL templates?

---

Making a simple `GET https://api.github.com/` request, I get a collection of URLs in response, e.g. (excerpt):

```json
{
  "current_user_url": "https://api.github.com/user",
  "user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",
  "user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&;amp;page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "label_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/labels?q={query}&;amp;repository_id={repository_id}{&amp;page,per_page}"
}
```

I can surely make some guesses about how to interpret some parts of the syntax:

- `{user}` in `/users/{user}` is a required path parameter;
- `{/gist_id}` is an optional path parameter;
- `{?type,page,per_page,sort}` is a list of query parameters (unordered, all optional);
- etc.

… but it feels wrong to guess, and I couldn't find any explanation of this syntax on the Internet.

Can somebody help me understand, what are the constructs of this syntax and how to parse it?

Comment: Did you try looking at each endpoint in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference)? They generally give more details about the syntax (example with [/users/{username}](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#get-a-user)). Now, if you only look for a generally syntax explanation, I'm not sure there is one available.

Comment: Yeah, that’s one way to do that, thanks! Although, yes, I’m looking for a general syntax description

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: It's [URI Template](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570).

---

Here GitHub uses the syntax described in [RFC 6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570), known as **[URI Template](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570)**. Briefly, there are [several kinds of substitution](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-1.2) (or "variable expansion" as they call it in the paper), and each is denoted by a certain symbol.

For example:

- `/orgs/{org}` — "[simple string expansion](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.2)"; the default kind.

  > […] a single named variable is replaced by its value as a string
  > after pct-encoding any characters not in the set of unreserved URI
  > characters

  Can be seen in `code_search_url`, `commit_search_url`, `issue_search_url`, `label_search_url`, `organization_url`, `organization_repositories_url`, `organization_teams_url`, `repository_url`, `repository_search_url`, `topic_search_url`, `user_url`, `user_repositories_url`, and `user_search_url`.
- `/applications{/client_id}` — "[path segments, slash-prefixed](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.6)"; denotes that the variables compose a path segment.

  > For each defined variable in the variable-list, append "/" to the
  > result string and then perform variable expansion

  Can be seen in `current_user_authorizations_html_url`, `following_url`, `gists_url`, and `starred_url`.
- `/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}` — "[form-style query expansion](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.8)"; query with the first parameter.

  > […] useful for describing an entire optional query component

  Can be seen in `organization_repositories_url`, `current_user_repositories_url`, and `user_repositories_url`.
- `/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}` — "[form-style query continuation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.9)"; query without the first parameter.

  > […] useful for describing optional &name=value pairs in a template that already contains a literal query component with fixed parameters

  Can be seen in `code_search_url`, `commit_search_url`, `issue_search_url`, `label_search_url`, `repository_search_url`, `topic_search_url`, and `user_search_url`.

The RFC 6570 standard, however, defines many more expansion kinds.

---

For reference, this is the response from `GET https://api.github.com/` at the time of writing (an excerpt of only relevant properties):

```json
{
  "code_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "commit_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "current_user_authorizations_html_url": "https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}",
  "current_user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",
  "issue_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "label_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/labels?q={query}&repository_id={repository_id}{&page,per_page}",
  "organization_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "organization_teams_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/teams",
  "organization_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}",
  "repository_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "topic_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/topics?q={query}{&page,per_page}",
  "user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}",
  "user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}"
}
```

Comment: This means that they could have written `{/owner,repo}` in both `repository_url` (instead of `/{owner}/{repo}`) and `starred_url` (instead of `{/owner}{/repo}`). I have no idea why they chose not to